# Angular Unit Testing a resource request

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am attempting to perform a unit test on this controller.

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', [])
.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', 'myAppService'], function($scope, myAppService) {
    var _data = myAppService.requests.get(function() {
        $scope.requests = _data.requests;
    });
});
```

myAppService is a service based on ngResource.

I want to test for the number of requests. I spent all day figuring out how to get $httpBackend injected, now I'm hung up on properly measuring the data.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/requests').respond(
        {requests: [{sender: 'joe', message: 'help'}, {sender: 'larry', message: 'SOS'}]}
    );
});
it('should have a properly working Dashboard controller', inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var ctrl = $controller('DashboardController', {
        $scope : $scope
    });
    expect($scope.requests.length).toBe(2);
}));
```

Any assistance would be greatly, massively appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, everything looks ok.  There are two things that I think might be missing from your code though.

**First**, this method doesn't look quite right:

```
var _data = myAppService.requests.get(function() {
        $scope.requests = _data.requests;
    });
```

If you are providing a callback function, shouldn't that be passing in the data:

```
myAppService.requests.get(function(_data) {
    $scope.requests = _data.requests;
});
```

It is hard to tell without seeing your `myAppService` code (that is using `$resource`).

**Second**, in order to flush through the ajax response you need to call `$httpBackend.flush();` before you make your assertion with expect:

```
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var ctrl = $controller('DashboardController', {
        $scope : $scope
    });
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.requests.length).toBe(2);
```

From the `$httpBackend` [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend):

> **flush(count):**
>    Flushes all pending requests using the trained responses.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were correct, it was the flush().

There was an additional issue, there were other API calls that I didn't bother to intercept via $httpBackend; ALL of them need to be addressed or the test will error out.

That callback function syntax, yeah, it's weird, I'm working with a guy who likes to set them up that way, I didn't think it was bother arguing over.  --- THANK YOU SO MUCH